# Mysql: Select all values alphabetically between two strings in a table

Tags: mysql, select, alphabetical

Okay let's say I have this in my table:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | tom |
| 2 | anna |
| 3 | beatrice |
| 4 | robert |
| 5 | xavier |
| 6 | zoe |
| 7 | eustace |

How can I select all ids of the names that are alphabetically sorted?

Say, `select * from myTable where name "between" 'beatrice' and 'tom' order by name;`

Should give me :

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | beatrice |
| 7 | eustace |
| 4 | robert |
| 1 | tom |

Because in alphabetical order, those are in between 'beatrice' and 'tom'.

Comment: You posted the solution. What's the problem with it? (btw, remove those double quotes)

Comment: note that case sensitivity is dependent on the collation setting of the column;  most of the time "Eustace" will also be between "beatrice" and "tom"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the ID's you need:

```
select id from myTable where name between 'beatrice' and 'tom' order by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since these are strings, try this:

```
SELECT id
FROM tableName
WHERE nameField >= 'Landon' and nameField <= 'Peter'
ORDER BY nameField;
```

If you want to use the full name (first and last), you can try with that too.